# Missing Template PDFkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, middleware, pdfkit

I dropped the gem into the gem file, bundle installed it.

Have this in my application.rb:

```
require 'pdfkit'
config.middleware.use PDFKit::Middleware, :print_media_type => true
```

Doing rake middleware, I see 'use PDFKit::Middleware' in there.

I have this in my routes

```
match "/option_invoice/view_invoice/(/:id)" => "option_invoice#view_invoice"
```

Now when I go to http://0.0.0.0:3000/option_invoice/view_invoice/2.pdf, I got the missing template error. The page without the .pdf displays perfectly fine.

> Missing template option_invoice/view_invoice, application/view_invoice with {:formats=>> >[:pdf], :locale=>[:en], :handlers=>[:coffee, :erb, :builder, :arb]}.

I'm on rails 3.2.2 if that helps.

Any help?

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but did you try restarting the server?

Comment: Can you include the output of the rake routes command.  Also is there more information with the "Missing template" message about where it is looking for the template.  Have you written a template to generate the pdf from, and if so, where is that located

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're just missing a template in given paths that corresponds to view_invoice.pdf.erb or view_invoice.pdf.haml or whatever you are using.

Either you create that and render whichever view you want in the PDF or you override the default template pulled by PDFKit.

I would recommend the first variant, this makes the rendered PDF independent of your views (kind of).

Cheers!